# javascript/jQuery: how to use var from click event in jQuery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, global-variables, jquery-ui-dialog

Using jQuery dialog to open a modal box to confirm e.g. to delete a specific user from friends. I would like to use the friends name in the modal box (currently I print it with `php` in the `name`-tag of the link and use jQuery to get it from there).

```
//create the html for the modal box
var dialog_html_ignore = $('<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Ignore Friend Request?"><p>Some text... ignore [put the name here], ...?</p></div>')

//set up the jQuery dialog
var dialog_ignore=$( dialog_html_ignore ).dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "No": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Yes": function() {
                window.location.href = targetUrl;
            }
        }
    });

//open the dialog on click event
$('.click_ignore').click(function() {
    window.fName = $(this).attr("name");
    alert(fName); /* this gives me the right username */
    dialog_ignore.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

How/what is the best way to use the username variable actually as a part of the text (in the html of the modal box)??

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: which value you need? That fname?

Comment: @RajaGopal: yes, the frame (which value is in the `name` attribute of the clicked `a` element)...

Comment: this is really easy to do as Rory's solution points out, since the dialog window is actually just a div on the parent page, all of your selectors work just as if it were a DOM element on your page (since it is)

Comment: @jbabey: yes, you are right.. I can see now how easy it actually is! Thank you for very much your help and sorry, I am still quite new and unexperienced... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dialog_html_ignore = $('<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Ignore Friend Request?"><p>Some text... ignore <span class="name"></span>, ...?</p></div>')

$('.click_ignore').click(function() {
    window.fName = $(this).attr("name");
    $(".name", dialog_html_ignore).text(fName);
    dialog_ignore.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ft5D8/1)

Comment: thank you very much Rory! This is wonderful, works perfectly and is easily adaptable for any number of variables... thank you, your solution opened my eyes once again what all is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

I would write the dialog HTML as actual HTML in the page, not as a string to be parsed by `$`.  Then, I would select it by ID and dialog-ify it so it is hidden at once.

I'd also include an empty `<span id='ignore-dialog-fname'></span>` in the dialog HTML and then select by ID to set its `textContent`/`innerText` to `fname`.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    //set up the jQuery dialog
    var dialog_ignore=$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "No": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Yes": function() {
                window.location.href = targetUrl;
            }
        }
    });

    //open the dialog on click event
    $('.click_ignore').click(function() {
        window.fName = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#ignore-dialog-fname").text(fName);
        dialog_ignore.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Ignore Friend Request?">
    <p>Some text... ignore <span id='ignore-dialog-fname'></span>, ...?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for the answer. is there a specific reason to write the html in the html page rather than in js? The reason I'm doing it this way, is that if the page does not load very quickly, you can see the html for a moment (although just a flash)... unless you would hide it, of course..

Comment: I was also concerned that `$("#ignore-dialog-fname")` would not be accessible if the HTML was only known the the dialog handler (that is, I didn't know if `.dialog` would automatically add the dialog HTML to the DOM).  My concern is apparently unfounded if Rory's solution works.  Use that, since it's basically the same as mine and doesn't make you rewrite your code.

Comment: hey, thank you for your effort, really! and for giving it so honestly to Rory.. but his solution works really fine, did not expect that it was that easy... :) thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in your click event,

```
dialog_html_ignore.attr("name", fname);
```

In dialog box you can access like this

```
dialog_html_ignore.attr("name");
```

Comment: That will just get/set the attribute, not the visible text of the element. I don't see how this has so many upvotes?